# How to set a size of a select drop down menu in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

The normal way to do this would be:

```
var resultSelect = document.getElementById("resultSelect");
resultSelect.size = 3;
```

How do i do this in jQuery?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using jQuery, how can I dynamically set the size attribute of a select box?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65206/using-jquery-how-can-i-dynamically-set-the-size-attribute-of-a-select-box)

Comment: Hi Felix. I didn't see it as one of the suggestions when asking the question. It definitely is a duplicate :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
$("#resultSelect").attr('size', '3');
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers everyone. I have to attribute the answer to kchau for jumping in there first

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#mySelect').attr('size', value)
```

[Using jQuery, how can I dynamically set the size attribute of a select box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65206/using-jquery-how-can-i-dynamically-set-the-size-attribute-of-a-select-box)

Comment: Thanks for the link. That question didn't pop up as one of the suggestions when i wrote the question :(