# Using jQuery to increase the size attribute of HTML select box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML select box with a `size` of 1 to start and would like to increase that each time a new option is inserting into the box. I am able to insert the options with no problem but I can't figure out the correct way to increase the size. I tried following [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65206/using-jquery-how-can-i-dynamically-set-the-size-attribute-of-a-select-box) but the code is not working and I am not really seeing what I am missing.

Here is the relevant code:

```
var currentSize = $("#SelectedProjects").attr("size");
currentSize++;
alert(currentSize);
$("SelectedProjects").attr("size", currentSize);
```

As a test I am alerting the `currentSize` and that alert returns the right number but when I try to assign it the box does not grow. What am I missing here?

Comment: Missing `#` on second `$("#SelectedProjects")`.

Comment: Did you try `$("#SelectedProjects").attr('size', '3');` ?

Comment: If you're going to repeatedly select an element (or group of elements) I'd recommend making a local variable as a cache, rather than a look-up each time - `var $selectedProducts = $("#SelectedProducts");`  Doing that would also have solved your typo problem :)

Comment: Thanks everyone. Been a long, frustrating day and it is starting to show in my code.

Comment: Typo's happen, it doesn't make you bad, they're inevitable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last line of code is missing the `#` refer to an element with the id of `SelectedProjects`.  Instead, now it is looking for a `SelectedProjects` element.

Fix this by adding the missing `#`:

```
var currentSize = $("#SelectedProjects").attr("size");
currentSize++;
alert(currentSize);
$("#SelectedProjects").attr("size", currentSize);
<!-- ^^^^^ here -->
```

Hope this helps.